# Select all foreign key constraint defs for relations of a specific parent table

Tags: postgresql

I have a parent table called `users` which **has** multiple relations `emails` and `phone_numbers`. The `users` table resides in a schema called `it` and the tables `emails` and `phone_numbers` resides in a schema called `da`. Now I need to query all constraint definitions for tables that **belongs to** the `it.users` table. In pseudo code this would be:

```
SELECT relational_table_name, constraint_def 
  FROM some_information_tables 
  WHERE parent_schema_name = 'users' 
    AND parent_schema_name = 'it'
```

How do I do this in the real world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
SELECT c.relname as relation, c2.relname as parent, pg_get_constraintdef(cons.oid) as condef
FROM pg_class c
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_constraint cons ON cons.conrelid = c.oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_class c2 ON cons.confrelid = c2.oid
WHERE c.relkind = 'r'
AND (cons.contype = 'f')
AND c2.relname in ('users')
GROUP BY relation, parent, condef
```